# Как установить ограничение переменной?

Tags: pascal

К примеру есть переменная N. Есть условие, что переменная должна быть (2 ≤ N ≤ 10^4)
Как это записать в Pascal?

Comment: Хитрый вопрос. Можно дать хитрый ответ:

    var N:2..10000;

Подозреваю, что это не совсем то, что хотел @borealis96

При необходимости можно включить проверку диапазонов (Range checking). Если в используемой системе она есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если я правильно понял, может быть так

```
IF ((N >= 2) AND (N <= 10000)) THEN BEGIN ... END;
```

?

**[Updated]**

Ну или есть волшебная формула, если речь идет об этом

```
x^y = exp(ln(x) * y)
```